# On/Off NFC system setting through Phonegap

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, nfc

I am using chariotsolution's nfc plugin for phonegap (https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc) and it's all working perfect for reading Nfc Tag.
In my application there is toggle button that want to On/Off NFC system setting through programmatically in phonegap. Is that possible with an app?

There is method, to show setting but not to On/Off.

```
nfc.showSettings();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't programmatically turn NFC on and off. The `nfc.showSettings` function starts an intent that opens the NFC settings so the user can enable (or disable) NFC. https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcshowsettings

Use `nfc.enabled` to check if NFC is enabled. https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcenabled

Both of these functions wrap the Android NFC APIs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#isEnabled()